# How to apply Ascending order sorting on Months(like APR-17,APR-18,AUG-17,DEC-18,DEC17) in COGNOS Graph

Tags: sorting, graph, cognos

[image]

How to apply Ascending order sorting on Months(like APR-17,APR-18,AUG-17,DEC-18,DEC17) in COGNOS Graph
I did try my best with default properties to sort x-axis attribute but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a text Column Containing the same datefield with date format specifier of 'MMYYYY'. Sort the result on this field.  It will give you the appropriate sort order you are seeking.
ie

```
APR-17 == 042017
APR-18 == 042018
AUG-17 == 082017
AUG-18 == 082018
DEC-17 == 122017
DEC-18 == 122018
```